# Cygwin SSH public key auth UNC network path "not a directory"

Tags: ssh, cygwin, rsync, public-key, unc

I have a unique problem when accessing a Cygwin based SSH Server through public key (rsa) based authentication.

If I login to the server via password auth:

```
ssh Administrator@domain.com
```

I login just fine and can then either execute:

```
cd //anotherpc/shareName
```

or `cd /backup/anotherpc` where this is a symlink to the aforementioned network share

This is successful and I can access anything on that share without issue.

The problem arises if i do the same thing above just after logging in using a public key authentication mechanism.

The error output is:

```
cd //anotherpc/shareName
-bash: cd: //anotherpc/shareName: Not a directory
```

Update:

The /etc/sshd_config file has the following commands having removed all commented out lines:

```
Port 22
StrictModes no
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/sbin/sftp-server
```

It is extremely strange.  Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Kind Regards

Comment: The trailing `/` in the error message but not in the `cd` command is suspicious; I'd expect it to print the directory path exactly as you typed it. Are you sure you've shown us the *exact* command and error message?

Comment: I thought the slash was odd when I was writing the post.  I have just re-run my test and the slash does not appear in the error message, so maybe it was a typo....  I will ammend the question to reflect the correction.

Comment: It's possible to set up the ssh to do different actions depending on the key used.  What does the associated key entry in `authorized_keys` look like on the server?  If there's nothing strange there, check for special setup in sshd configuration file which may cause a different action to be taken depending on login credentials.

Comment: The authorized key file currently has two lines with the format:

ssh-rsa AAAA............sjn username@remoteServer

I will take a closer look at the sshd config later on when I have a few more minutes to spare

Comment: In my /etc/sshd_config file I have removed all of the commented out lines, and has been added to the original question as I can't seem to have carriage returns in my comments.

Comment: @Mark: Formatting in comments is very limited. Click the "help" link next to the text box for more information.

Comment: I *may* have found a solution to the issue.  This page fully describes the answer:

<http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-setuid-overview 
I will post a proper answer if I can confirm the issue is resolved

Answer (score 1):

If you run this command before trying to access a network share, the required authentication token will be created.

net use '\machineName\shareName' /user:"DOMAIN\Username" password

For full details see:

See http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-setuid-overview